# Make a program that will ask for product code, the quantity of the product, and sums up all the prices

Tags: java, arrays, swing, loops, compiler-errors

I've been having a hard time doing this and I've been searching for ideas on how to code it down but I'm still a beginner. Here's my source code. Maybe you'll get my idea by reading it. It's not running well as it should be though.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class sto
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        char s;
        do
        {
            int pcod=0, qua;
            int[] cod={101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110};
            double[] pri={1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5, 6.6, 7.7, 8.8, 9.9, 0.1};
            double [] sal=new double[10];
            String[] pro={"q", "w", "e", "r", "t", "y", "u", "i", "o", "p"};
            do
            {
                if(pcod>=101||pcod<=110)
                {
                    pcod=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter Product Code:"));
                    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
                    {
                        if(pcod==cod[i])
                        {
                            qua=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter quantity:"));
                            sal[i]=pri[i]*qua;
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You bought:\n"+pro[i]+"......"+pri[i]+" Pesos x"+qua);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                if(pcod<=101||pcod>=110)
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"INVALID PRODUCT CODE");
                    //some codes here to make you return to enter a product code again.
            }while(pcod!=00);
            for(int d=0;d<10;d++)
                sal[d]=qua;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Total sales.........."+sal[d]+" Pesos");
            s=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Shop Again?(Y/N)").charAt(0);
        }
        while(s=='y');
    }
}
```

Comment: *"It's not running well as it should be though"* What is the expected output?  What is the *actual* output?  +1 for making an attempt and showing that attempt.

Comment: `sto.java:37: error: cannot find symbol`  For a compilation problem, be sure to copy/paste the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// .. the problem is in the next few lines
for(int d=0;d<10;d++)
    sal[d]=qua;
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Total sales.........."+sal[d]+" Pesos");
```

Lacking brackets, the `for` loop only includes the next, indented code line.  The attribute `d` is defined inside the `for` loop statement, and *goes out of focus* beyond the loop (cannot be referenced/used in the option pane).

To fix it, put `{` and `}` around the two lines (one set of brackets to include both lines).

That leads to the next problem.

```
int pcod=0, qua;
```

At this point, `pcod` is `0` but `qua` has no value.  The compiler will warn, `might not have been initialized`.  The quick fix is to give it a default value, but that might not fit the logic of the app., especially if an exception is thrown while parsing the input to an `int` value.

Answer (score 0):

I think your

```
if(pcod>=101|| pcod<=110)
```

is wrong, if you want pcod to be between 101 and 110 you would want to use &&.

It also looks like you never actually set pcod to anything else then zero before entering your loops? Is this correct? :)

Cheers.